# How do I maintain a button state across pages

Tags: javascript, html, django

In my project I'm using normal **HTML** for front-end and **Django** for back-end. There I have a ***login system.***

---

I have two questions on that:

1. When the user logs-in how do I detect it in HTML and change the Login button to show Log out.
2. How do I maintain this changes across pages. So, that when I navigate to a different page after login it keeps showing the logout button.

---

> Don't suggest me react. I have come a long way from where I can change
> my technology stack for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Session Storage** for storing the login state of the page for the current session only.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', true);
```

Fetching the Login Status while displaying the button :

```
var isLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');

if(isLoggedIn) {
   //code for logged-in users
}
```

---

Points to know about [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) :

- A page session lasts as long as the browser is open, and survives over page reloads and restores.
- Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.
- Opening multiple tabs/windows with the same URL creates sessionStorage for each tab/window.
- Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears objects in sessionStorage.

Comment: Should I do sessionStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', true); in Django

Comment: You can write the code in a <script> tag but not directly as a python script in Django.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save as a variable such as `isLoggedIn` that will persist across different routes and on refreshes. Example when you want to save

```
window.localStorage.set("isLoggedIn", "true");
```

When you want to check if they're logged in

```
const isLoggedIn = window.localStorage.get("isLoggedIn");
```

Comment: like when I render any other page i will just check if loggedin ==true can you please explain me a little bit more

Comment: You will need to call `const isLoggedIn = window.localStorage.get("isLoggedIn");` whenever you reload/change pages and then run your logic on `if (isLoggedIn == true)`

Comment: But the question is how do I get the login succesful from django